# Change color of multiple menu items when one is hovered

Tags: javascript, css, hover

[See my CodePen](https://codepen.io/alanvkarlik/pen/pVzLpQ)

My menu has 4 links. When you enter the website I want them all to be Black.

When you hover Link1 - then Link2, 3 and 4 should become transparent with Black outline, while Link1 should change color to Red.

Same with Link2 - when you hover Link2, it should become Red, while Links 1, 3 and 4 should be transparent with Black outline. Etc.

When none of them are hovered - they go Black again.

For transparency I use this code:

```
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
```

Is it possible to set this up in CSS or do I have to use JS? If so, how to do it?

Here's the code:
HTML:

```
<div class="main">
                <a class="hover_link l1" href="">Link1</a>
                / 
                <a class="hover_link l2" href="">Link2</a>
                /
                <a class="hover_link l3" href="">Link3</a>
                /
                <a class="hover_link l4" href="">Link4</a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  position: relative;
}
.main {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 54%;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
.hover_link, .l1, .l2, .l3, .l4 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight:900;
  color: black;
}
.hover_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
}
```

I tried using this:

```
a.l1:hover > a.l2, a.l3, a.l4 {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

But doesn't work -_-'

Comment: use '+' selector or `~`

Comment: is there a way to make it work but only when you hover the Text, not the whole area around it? currently 'main' class includes both Text and the space inbetween...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the primary hover to the wrapping div.

**In other words, the hover kicks in to change all links when the `.main` is hovered BUT an additional style is added when the link itself is hovered.**

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 54%;
  font-size: 24px;
  /* for demo purposes */
}

.hover_link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 900;
  color: black;
}

.main:hover .hover_link {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}

.main:hover .hover_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a class="hover_link l1" href="">Link1</a> /
  <a class="hover_link l2" href="">Link2</a> /
  <a class="hover_link l3" href="">Link3</a> /
  <a class="hover_link l4" href="">Link4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to make it work but only when you hover the Text, not the whole area around it? currently 'main' class includes both Text and the space inbetween...

Comment: No, that's no possible...you can't select backward or upwards in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this by using the hover on the main container:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 54%;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}

.hover_link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 900;
  color: black;
}

.main:hover a {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
a.hover_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a class="hover_link" href="">Link1</a> /
  <a class="hover_link" href="">Link2</a> /
  <a class="hover_link" href="">Link3</a> /
  <a class="hover_link" href="">Link4</a>
</div>
```